# Size of a google doc inside of google drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api, scribe

Is there a way to get length (byte size) of a google document via the google drive
api? The metadata shows the size for a uploaded file, but not for a google
document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documents in Google native formats do not use any user quota, so the Drive API will always return 0 as their byte size.

Comment: Is there a way to get the "real" byte size?

Comment: No, as there's no way to get the file in the native format. What is your use case?

Comment: I'm making a "proxy" to get files from my google drive account. And i need to do some commands that we use in shell. Eg: ls, cp, getattr, etc. For my getattr command i need the name, length, modified_date and boolean that indicates that file is a folder or not. My problem is in the "length" attribute. I can get the length for uploaded files but not for google documents.

Comment: You should use 0 as the length of those documents